# JavaFx print arabic Text

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I try to print node with javafx this node content arabic text, this is my code

```
private void print(Node node) {
   PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
   if (job != null) {
       boolean printed = job.printPage(node);
       if (printed)
       {
           job.endJob();
       } else {
           System.out.println(job.getJobStatus());
       }
   }   
}
```

but the result is not like in the node, the words are rotate. any one have solution please

Comment: The code you posted does not help in solving your problem. You need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You will need to explain what “the words are rotate” means.  Is the entire page printing out as portrait instead of landscape, or vice versa?

Comment: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Node+Orientation+in+JavaFX